# Listings package not working properly with Exam class

Tags: listings, exam

When I gave my code in the exam class like

```
\begin{parts}
\part \begin{lstlisting} 
echo The date is $date 
\end{lstlisting}
\part \begin{lstlisting} 
echo The date is $(date) 
\end{lstlisting}
\end{parts}
```

I want is the line starting with echo in (a) and (b) respectively. Instead that only `\part` displays only (a)

Comment: Add a blank line or a `\par` between `\end{lstlisting}` and `\part`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting it in `\lstinline` solved my problem

```
\begin{parts}
\part \lstinline{echo The date is $date}
\part \lstinline{echo The date is $(date)}
\end{parts}
```